# Can I use a different brand of underlayment under my Pergo laminate floor and still be covered under the warranty?

Tags: laminate-floor, underlayment

I am not sold on Pergo Gold brand Underlayment. From reading reviews, there seem to be a good amount of unhappy customers who have used it. They say it crunches under the flooring when you walk on it.

Can I use a different brand of underlayment under my laminate floor and still be covered under the warranty?  I am not doing the install myself, I am having it installed through Lowe's.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can use any brand of underlayment as long as it meets Pergo's specifications. Their warranty is concise and straightforward and the only reference to an underlayment is made in the "Conditions" section, and it reads as follows:

> Foam underlayment should meet or exceed 2.0 lb polyethylene foam (1.9-2 lb density), CFC Free, 1.8mm to 2.1mm thickness.

By the way, according to Pergo's installation instructions, an underlayment is required only when it's not attached to the flooring.

Comment: AND for flooring WITH an attached underlayment, Pergo says: • Foam underlayment is pre-attached to this product. No additional underlayment is required for proper performance. "Use of an additional underlayment will void the warranty."